# WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0 installed but publisher and devportal not openning

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I installed API Manager 3.0.0 and started. But I cannot open https://localhost:9443/publisher/ and dev portal in browser. I am getting the following error

```
syntaxError: invalid for/in left-hand side index.bundle.js:31:204560
```

What can I do to make it right?

Comment: What is your browser version and WSO2 API Manager version, is it 3.0.0 GA or WUM updated server? 
Can you add the complete browser logs, or a screenshot of the browser's developer console ?

Comment: my browser is firefox version 45 update to 72 thats ok, thanks